# How to update Android Things-Apps?

Tags: android, updates, android-things

With [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/index.html), Android apps can also be run on IoT devices like a Raspberry Pi & Co. Right now, apps have to be installed via `adb`.

**What if those apps need to be updated**, for example to fix a security issue? Many IoT devices have no display and using `adb` is quite complicated, especially when there are a lot of devices in need of an update.

Does anybody know how such updates will be handled?

Comment: My understanding is that Weave will take care of that in the future. It is not yet available with Android Things but it will be included in a future release https://developers.google.com/weave/

Comment: Yes, that's what I found out too :) But no one says when the "future" actually will be :/

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

Since Developer Preview 6, Android Things-Apps can be updated via the [Developer Console](https://partner.android.com/things/console/). DP6 also offers a new partition scheme used for updates and a [UpdateManager](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/update/UpdateManager.html) class to control them manually. Read the full blog post [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/android-things-developer-preview-6.html).

*Old answer:*

---

Okay, the answer is hiding at the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/weave/

> Android Things is a turnkey solution that provides certified hardware to build IoT devices. [...] **In the future, Android Things will be updated to include *infrastructure for pushing updates***, Weave connectivity, and more.

So we have to use `adb` to install updates for now :/

Comment: I believe it is now possible to update Android Thing apps: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-things-console-developer-preview.html